# Parse PFGeoPoint save location getting started

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, cllocation

Im trying to create an app with two user types...one sends a location and the other user type (on a different device) searches an area and finds the closest user.

I have been on parse's website and stack overflow...they all seem to start in the middle. I would like to have somebody explain the first steps

Heres my code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,   
CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate,  
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var photographer1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buyer1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var searchController:UISearchController!
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}
// to run the animation this sec of code checks if the region was changed


 var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

 func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
    let view = self.mapView.subviews[0]
    //  Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region change is from user interaction
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()
    if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
        // user changed map region
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
        hobo()

//            
        buyer1.center = CGPointMake(188.0, 513.0)

        photographer1.center = CGPointMake(188.0, 581.0)

    }
}

// your boy

//     MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){
    //1
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    //2
    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        //3
        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)

    }
}

func hobo(){
    print("testing")
}

@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func locateMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    buyer1.center = CGPointMake(188.0, 581.0)

    photographer1.center = CGPointMake(188.0, 513.0)

}

@IBAction func photographer(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func buyer(sender: AnyObject) {
}

}
```

Comment: did you make sure you have the permission from the user to use the GPS location

Comment: @Lamour i have NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription & NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.........do i need additional permissions?

Comment: there is a method that checks if the permission status has change `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method

Comment: i added that no change, its weird it works fine if i select my device, but if i select a device simulator it fails

Comment: reset the simulator and change the simulator gps location, if the code works fine in your phone but not in the simulator it means the app cannot get your location from the simulator